# how to see console output in netbeans ide 6.8

Tags: servlets, netbeans6.8

i have a servlet i want to see output on console,my servlet is running if i replace System.out.println with out.println

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");  
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + request.getContextPath () 
            + "  </h1>");
        System.out.println("exit");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

    } finally { 
        out.close();
    }
}
```

the exit is not getting displayed on console.
can anyone tell me the reason

Comment: What do you mean with "console". NB has an Output window (Ctrl-4), where the message should appear.

Comment: yes but it is not showing the System.out.println() output

Comment: Did you try System.err.println ? What is about to upgrade to Netbeans 7.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out your sample code, but its working well. And I used GlassFish as the server, so in the console it gives `INFO: exit` as the result. I think your `"exit"`text is not noticeable. Prefix your `"exit"` with some `"*"` marks and see....

Comment: are u seeing it in log of server

Comment: yes... of course.. if you cannot see it please go to _Window->Services-> Servers_ and select and right click your server and "View Server Log"