# Where can I see system.out.println message?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I have a helper class like this:

```
public class FtHelper {

    Session session = null;

    public FtHelper() {
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }

    public FinancialTransactions getByBeginDate(String beginDate) {

        List<FinancialTransactions> FtList = null;

        try {
            org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery(
                    "from FinancialTransactions where DATE=:date")
                    .setParameter("date", beginDate);
            FtList = (List<FinancialTransactions>) q.list();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return FtList.get(0);
    }
}
```

I add a `System.out.println(beginDate);` just above return, but it doesn't appear to print anything. I also used `System.out.println("anytext")`, but it didn't work either. Where can I see that output message in Netbeans? By the way, I get the value `beginDate` from my JSF.

Comment: Where the thing running? Is this a webapp? What webserver is it running on?

Comment: It's console output - see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355087/how-to-see-console-output-in-netbeans-ide-6-8

Comment: This is a webapp yeah. Server is tomcat

Comment: Then the output would be in the tab that shows tomcat's console logs.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the output (most of the time) in `catalina.out`.

Under `Windows`, you should be able to find it in the folder: `<Tomcat Folder>\logs`